# Android: LocationManager WiFi Position

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Im using this code but i only get the location when the GPS is on... Can you tell me why? I wanna use the WiFi especially.

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    //Sorgt für die Updates

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 60 * 1000, 0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60 * 1000, 0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60 * 1000, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Werte hochladen, MYSQL
    new DatabaseConnector(false).execute()
}
```

Comment: What is the Location Mode set to on your device?

Comment: Hope you've ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in your manifest ?

Comment: Permissions are given. I want to get position by wifi so i turn just the wifi on. But doesnt work. But when i turn also the gps on the wifi also gets the location.

Comment: did you print the log in onLocationChanged() with llcation.getProvider() to know if the locaiton is from network ?
When you turn on GPS, as you requested for PASSIVE_PROVIDER also it may be the case that your app has received location from other app (passive loc).

Comment: I dont use logs but i load all the data on a database so I see there which one it is.

On my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact the mode is called Location and not GPS. So I guess it activates every Provider (GPS, Network, Passive) by turning it on. 

Right now I have only NETWORK_PROVIDER in my code. And when I start the app without activating the Location Mode on my phone I dont get the Location. When I turn it on it works.

I guess this is something new. Giving the user the info that by activiting Location not just the GPS will get the data but also WiFi and so on. What do you think?